# Consistency of DirectX models

Tags: xna, directx

Is there a way to check the consistency of a DirectX model (.x) ?

Whilst compiling .x files with XNA GameStudio 3.1 compilation is aborted with the following error message:

`Error  2   Could not read the X file. The file is corrupt or invalid. Error code: D3DXFERR_PARSEERROR. C:\WFP\Browser\Content\m.x  KiviBrowser`

Some models compile correctly without any error/warning and some abort as described. The files of each model have several thousand lines.

I am creating the files in Googles SketchUp 8 where they all look fine and don't show any sign of corruption.

Suppose I have such a model my XNA compiler won't compile because their is an inconsistency somewhere in the file - how could I identify this in order to correct it ?